# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefault' of undefined in momentjs,, moment.tz()

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, undefined, moment-timezone

I have an JS file in a npm enviornment and it and its associated package.json is given below.
I receive the following ERROR, while running the file 'app.js'.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefault' of undefined

I am not able to access moment.tz() as it is getting the value of undefined.

app.js

```
import moment from "moment";

moment.tz.setDefault(moment.tz.guess());
console.log(moment().tz());
```

package.json

```
  "name": "folder_name_here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import from `moment-timezone` rather than `moment`.

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
```

Also, there's very little reason to do `moment.tz.setDefault(moment.tz.guess());` because the default time zone is already understood by Moment. If that's your only reason for using Moment-Timezone, then don't - just use Moment by itself.